# Return MVC view from razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 3.1. MVC web application and we want to start incorporating razor pages into it for some pages (or all going forward). We have a standard Error view that is currently used in a controller e.g.

```
if (!project.IsValid)
{
  return View("Error", project.Error.Message);
}
```

Now, using razor pages how can I put this same logic into the OnGetAsync method.. tried this but View is not recognised..

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string id)
        {
          var project = await _projectRepo.GetById(id);

          if (!project.IsValid)
          {
            return View("Error", project.Error.Message);
          }

          . . .

          return Page();
```

Is it possible to return a view in a razor page - we don't really want to have to create a duplicate razor page error view, or create some sort of error controller action if possible.

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else I got it to work by creating this extension method:

```
public static ViewResult View<TModel>(this PageModel pageModel, string viewName, TModel model) {
            var viewDataDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary<TModel>(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary()) {
                Model = model
            };
            foreach (var kvp in pageModel.ViewData)
                    viewDataDictionary.Add(kvp);

            return new ViewResult {
                ViewName = viewName,
                ViewData = viewDataDictionary,
                TempData = pageModel.TempData
            };
        }
```

And then using in razor page handler method..

```
...
return this.View("MvcViewName", model);
...
```

Haven't got a clue how to test this extension method though, so any help would be welcome

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I render my error view into a string with

```
public static async Task<string> RenderPartialViewToString(this Controller value, string viewName, object model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName)) { viewName = value.ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName; }

        value.ViewData.Model = model;




        IViewEngine viewEngine = value.ControllerContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(ICompositeViewEngine)) as ICompositeViewEngine;

        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            ViewEngineResult viewResult = viewEngine.FindView(value.ControllerContext, viewName, false);

            ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(
                value.ControllerContext,
                viewResult.View,
                value.ViewData,
                value.TempData,
                writer,
                new HtmlHelperOptions()
            );

            await viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);

            return writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From Razor Page Get or Post method:

```
    return new ViewResult
    {
        ViewName = "YourMVCViewName",
        ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<YourMVCModelType>(ViewData, YourMVCModelObject),
        TempData = TempData,
    };
```